# CASE THEN {INSTRUCTION}

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT registro.id_registro,cliente.name_cliente,estatus.name_estatus, vehiculo.id_vehiculo,vehiculo.tipo_vehiculo,vehiculo.modelo_vehiculo, vehiculo.color_vehiculo 
FROM registro 
JOIN cliente ON registro.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente
JOIN cajon ON registro.id_cajon = cajon.id_cajon
JOIN vehiculo ON registro.id_vehiculo = vehiculo.id_vehiculo
JOIN estatus ON cliente.id_estatus = estatus.id_estatus
WHERE registro.fs_registro IS NULL AND
CASE
WHEN nombre IS NOT NULL THEN cliente.name_cliente LIKE CONCAT('%', nombre, '%')
WHEN placa IS NOT NULL THEN vehiculo.id_vehiculo LIKE CONCAT('%', placa, '%')
WHEN tipo IS NOT NULL THEN vehiculo.tipo_vehiculo LIKE CONCAT('%', tipo, '%')
WHEN modelo IS NOT NULL THEN vehiculo.modelo_vehiculo LIKE CONCAT('%', modelo, '%')
END
ORDER BY registro.id_registro DESC
```

Estaba tratando de averiguar si en mi proceso almacenado es posible hacer esto. Estoy tratando de crear una consulta en la cual en el case me pudiera dar una específica orden para buscar dentro de la misma consulta, no sé si tenga sentido

Nombre, Placa, Tipo y Modelo son parte de los parámetros del proceso almacenado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ser `LIKE`, lo más sencillo, sería aprovechar los comodines y hacer `LIKE '%%'`, para lo cual debemos verificar si es `NULL` la variable:

```
WHERE registro.fs_registro IS NULL AND
      cliente.name_cliente LIKE CONCAT('%', IFNULL(nombre,''), '%')
      AND ...
```

Sino, otra forma un poco más compleja es considerar las dos condiciones de la variable en el filtro:

```
WHERE registro.fs_registro IS NULL AND
      (nombre IS NULL 
       OR 
       (nombre IS NOT NULL AND cliente.name_cliente LIKE CONCAT('%', nombre, '%')
      ) AND ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D. Creo que haré la que tu hiciste